# How does "sort by vote" work for search results (possible bug)?

Tags: bug, status-completed, search

**Update 2:**

This issue seems to be solved now although I would like to know what the problem was.

---

I thought the results are sorted by the number of votes of the **question**. But now I encountered this:

When I search for example [`jquery variable name`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?&tab=votes&q=jquery%20variable%20name), the last results on the [**first** page](https://stackoverflow.com/search?page=1&tab=votes&q=jquery%20variable%20name) have these votes:

---

[image]

---

Whereas the top results on [page **two**](https://stackoverflow.com/search?page=2&tab=votes&q=jquery%20variable%20name) are:

---

[image]

---

What is going on here? Seems like a bug to me or did I miss something (again) on meta?

---

**Update:**

What is the status of this? I would like to hear something like *ok we will take a look at it* or *this is by design*.

Or is it not a problem at all? For me the behaviour is very unintuitive.

Comment: I'm getting this behaviour as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was indeed a bug -- artifact of the switch to Lucene.NET for search results:

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/stack-overflow-search-now-81-less-crappy/